# Spark got stuck with BlockManager when computing connected components using GraphX

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I'm computing connected components using Spark GraphX on AWS EC2.
I believe the computation was successful, as I saw the type information of the final result.
However, it looks like Spark was doing some cleanup. The BlockManager removed a bunch of blocks and stuck at

> 15/07/04 21:53:06 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing block rdd_334_4
>
> 15/07/04 21:53:06 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block rdd_334_4 of size
>   25986936 dropped from memory (free 15648106262)

There was *no error message*, no update for like an hour. If I press the Enter key, I got disconnected from the cluster. Does anyone happen to know what's going on here?

I used 8 r3.4xlarge instances. I have 7 million edges and 200 million vertices.

Thank you!

Comment: If you got the final result, whats the problem? The block manager does do cleanup in a variety of cases, if you got the final result there probably wouldn't be any more messages or updates. Try looking at the web ui to see if there are any jobs running & what the state was of the final job. If your problem is that you don't get to see the final result because log messages covered it up in the shell, try saving it to a local variable.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Because of the cleanup log messages, I didn't see "scala>", so I thought it's still working on something. If I press "Enter", I got disconnected. I finally tried typing the variable name, which actually worked. Sorry about the silly question. I'm fairly new to Spark. Thank you!

Comment: No worrries, I'll move my comment to an answer then if it did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block manager does do cleanup in a variety of cases, if you got the final result there probably wouldn't be any more messages or updates. Try looking at the web ui to see if there are any jobs running & what the state was of the final job. If your problem is that you don't get to see the final result because log messages covered it up in the shell, try saving it to a local variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is how exactly the issue got resolved. Because of the cleanup log messages, I didn't see "scala>", so I thought it's still working on something. If I press "Enter", I got disconnected. I finally tried typing the variable name, which actually worked.